# How much of the post-season 1 plot and setting of Severance was pre-planned?

Tags: screenplay, severance

Really enjoyed the first season of *Severance*, but I was very surprised how few of the mysteries and questions set up during the show got resolved in the finale.

As a result, I couldn't escape the nagging sense that the show had been written primarily to generate exciting cliffhangers to get viewers hooked. In fact, it seemed plausible that none of the big questions actually have answers: they were just posed to build a thrilling show, and the writers planned to backfill if it turned out to be a hit.

So do we know whether this is the case or not, or was the entire concept of Season 2 and beyond pre-planned in advance?

Comment: Erm...ever see *Lost* ?

Comment: @Paulie_D nope. Would genuinely be interested how it's relevant?

Comment: Lost is famous for the writers and showrunners setting up questions that are never actually resolved in the show.  Its the epitome of the 'we will work it out as we go along' school of show creation.

Comment: @BobTway don't watch Lost if you usually get invested in series with lots of interesting mysteries because most of it gets ruined / abandoned in the last season.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Dan Erickson, *Severance* creator, most of it has been pre-planned and he already has an ending in mind.

Dan Erickson responded to similar questions in an "Ask Me Anything" (AMA) post in Reddit /r/SeveranceAppleTVPlus — *[Hey everybody! I’m Dan Erickson, the creator and executive producer of Severance on Apple TV＋ AMA!](https://old.reddit.com/r/SeveranceAppleTVPlus/comments/u8tk1b/hey_everybody_im_dan_erickson_the_creator_and/)*

> **Question:** Did you anticipate this show being as huge of a hit as it is? With so many streaming services to compete with I would imagine it’s hard to predict what the outcome will be. That being said is there a higher arching story that you have preconceived for this show? Like 5 seasons and it would be wrapped up or are you taking it one season at a time?

> **Dan Erickson:** There's a general plan for what Lumon is doing and where it all goes. We really don't want to get 5 seasons in and realize we don't know how to get out!

<sup>- [Comments in the AMA post](https://old.reddit.com/r/SeveranceAppleTVPlus/comments/u8tk1b/hey_everybody_im_dan_erickson_the_creator_and/i5nb441/)</sup>

> **Question:** Do you have a clear idea of how long you would like to see the show run for? Is there an end that you are building to?

> **Dan Erickson:** I'd love 4 or 5 seasons. There's a lot of story to tell but I also don't think it needs to go on forever.

<sup>- [Comments in the AMA post](https://old.reddit.com/r/SeveranceAppleTVPlus/comments/u8tk1b/hey_everybody_im_dan_erickson_the_creator_and/i5nbb38/)</sup>

> **Question:** In terms of currently unanswered mysteries, what proportion have you fully decided on the answers to vs. are still open to possibilities?

> **Dan Erickson:** We have most of it answered in our heads. 80/20?

<sup>- [Comments in the AMA post](https://old.reddit.com/r/SeveranceAppleTVPlus/comments/u8tk1b/hey_everybody_im_dan_erickson_the_creator_and/i5n9jwi/)</sup>

> **Question:** When you came up with the idea for the series, did you also have an ending in mind? How does it feel to see your writing on screen, is there anything you would have wanted to do differently?

> **Dan Erickson:** I have a last scene in mind, and a lot of the story that will get us there. Trying to find the balance of having a plan and letting the show have its own life and grow organically based on what works.

<sup>- [Comments in the AMA post](https://old.reddit.com/r/SeveranceAppleTVPlus/comments/u8tk1b/hey_everybody_im_dan_erickson_the_creator_and/i5na6f9/)</sup>

Comment: Let's wait and see. Lindelof and Cuse used to say the same type of thing about Lost...